# Grafana: Gauge metric changes with the width of the panel

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, gauge

we're trying to visualize some basic metrics like number of API calls via Grafana using prometheus metrics. I've configured a gauge metric for one of the APIs. The problem I'm facing here is that the number in the gauge changes with the data points. Can someone please explain what is going wrong here and how this particular parameter is affecting the end result? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you panel configured, (more specific, what kind of reducer function selected in Panel options > Value options > Calculation) number of data points could influence displayed value in different ways.

Most obvious would be case if you selected `Total` as reducer and multiply number of data points by two, you'll (most likely) get near doubling of shown value.